# Turn 2 lists into 2-column text file

Tags: python, datetime

I want to turn two-column lists in python into a two-column text file. The first column type is datetime.datetime type and the other is float. I'm having issues writing the file into the format I want. This is my script (it's probably sloppy and inefficient):

```
    from dateutil.parser import parse

    surface='EPsurface_21Oct2015Compensated.LEV'
    dataS=[]
    levelS=[]
    tempS=[]
    dateS=[]
    with open(surface,mode='r', encoding='latin_1') as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            try:
                words=line.split()
                dateS.append(parse('{0} {1}'.format(words[0],words[1])))
                tempS.append(float(words[3]))
            except (TypeError,IndexError):
                pass
    filenames=[]
    #Put both columns into one list
    for i in range(len(tempS)):
        filenames.append([dateS[i],tempS[i]])
    #Convert items into string 
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        filenames[i][0]=str(filenames[i][0])
        filenames[i][1]=str(filenames[i][1])
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        filenames[i]=str(filenames[i]) 
    filenames=str(filenames)
    newfiles ='\n'.join(filenames)
    with open('testing.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(filenames)
```

The output looks like this:

```
["['2015-08-17 10:11:18', '27.572']", "['2015-08-17 10:31:18', '27.549']", "['2015-08-17 10:51:18', '32.964']", "['2015-08-17 11:11:18', '31.038']"
```

I want it to looks like:

```
'2015-08-17 10:11:18',27.572
'2015-08-17 10:31:18', 27.549
'2015-08-17 10:51:18', 32.964
```

Comment: is filenames your list of lists?

Comment: Yes, filenames is the dates and temps as one list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code to:

```
surface='EPsurface_21Oct2015Compensated.LEV'
with open(surface,mode='r', encoding='latin_1') as fileobj, open('testing.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in fileobj:
        try:
            words=line.split()
            dateS = str(parse('{0} {1}'.format(words[0],words[1])))
            tempS = str(float(words[3]))
            print("{0}, {1}".format(dateS, tempS), file=out)
        except (TypeError,IndexError):
            pass
```

I also advise you to use datetime.strptime for parsing your datetime if you know the format of your datetime string, as it is faster, because it does not have to guess the format.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
with open('testing.txt','w') as f:
    for (dateS, tempS) in filenames:
        # f.write("%s, %s\n" % (dateS, tempS))
        # or as the comments suggested
        f.write("{dte}, {tmp}\n".format(dte=dateS, tmp=tempS))
```

Comment: Using `%` format strings is deprecated as of version 2.6 I believe.  You should use `.format()` instead.

Comment: @zondo: It's definitely not deprecated, it's just that format strings are far more flexible, support user-defined types, don't require explicit indexing (and work with names as well as positional args), etc. `%` format strings are usually unnecessary, but they're definitely still supported (Python 3 later added support to allow `%` formatting using `bytes` format templates, which don't support a `.format` method).

Comment: @zondo @ShadowRanger ah, I just use `%` format strings for quick printing, I think it's fine for 2 vars, but I only end up using it when I need to make the template more readable, or I end up with too many variables. Thanks for the feedback though, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace last your line:

```
f.write('\n'.join('{0},{1}'.format(element[0], element[1]) for element in filenames))
```